# Rename [star-wars-imperial-assaul], it's missing a T

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

[star-wars-imperial-assaul](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-imperial-assaul) is missing a T.

I've created a [star-wars-imperial-assault](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars-imperial-assault) tag and added the same tag wiki and excerpt to it. Could the former be merged into it? I don't want to spam up the front page with edits if it can be avoided.